# Error in Angular 6 router

Tags: angular

I have the following router configuration:

```
export const appRouter: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [BaseResolver],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [InitResolver],
        children: []
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: AppErrorComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here I adding it to my Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      ...appRouter
    ]),
```

Also, I have a base href in my index.html template:

```
<base href="/er/site/"/>
```

When navigating to

```
http://localhost:4141/er/site/
```

The `BaseResolver` is working and being hooked, but when trying to go to:

```
http://localhost:4141/erapp/site/home
```

I am getting the following error:

```
core.js:1542 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1359)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1340)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1359)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1340)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

Same is happening when trying to navigate to error.

Comment: Remove `pathMatch: 'full'`.

Comment: You can make `pathMatch: 'prefix'` instead

Comment: @JBNizet, why??

Comment: @AmitChigadani, where?

Comment: I need the path: '', to work only when only when the path is '', not on every sub-route

Comment: @vlio20 If you give `pathMatch : full` to parent, then your child routes seem useless

Comment: *why??*: to avoid the problem you're facing, and be able to navigate to sub-routes.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, changing to prefix is working, but, the guard also runnig on every sub-route. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Remove it then: there is no component associated to the empty route, so it doesn't display anything anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet, I need it to run redirect, just for the `canActivate`, there is a logic that redirects to a different route according to some logic

Comment: @vlio20 Why not simply return from `canActivate` when matching route is not for a parent. If route is for a parent, only then execute your logic.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, I am not sure I can translate your suggestion into code, can you post a snippet please?

Comment: @vlio20 I have made an answer with my above comments. Please have a look.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, will do

Comment: An easier solution would be to avoid defining the two other routes as children of the empty path route.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, that is a good idea, he can simply use `redirectTo : er/site/home` instead of using a guard for default redirection.

Comment: I did as you suggested (move it to the top level) for some reason the redirect is till not working. Also, why are you adding the BaseHref to the route?

Comment: @AmitChigadani, redirect is not working

Comment: Going directly to the route works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment thread, modify your `CanActivate()` of `parent` route path accordingly, so that you don't have to perform any logic when the `child` route url is entered. I don't think we can skip `CanActivate()` of parent, while the entered url is child url. Either you have to remove or simply return as suggested below.

I am just adding a pseudocode here.  You can get the current url from `router.events`

```
canActivate() {
      if (this._routeURL == '/er/site/') {
          // matches parent route
          // do some navigation or perform any logic that you want to do
      }
      else if (this._routeURL == '/er/site/home') {
          // matches child route, so simply return
          return true;
      }
      else if (this._routeURL == '/er/site/error') {
          // matches child route, so simply return
          return true;
      }  
     return false;
}
```

And also modify as `pathMatch : prefix` in your parent route.

routing.module.ts

```
 export const appRouter: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    canActivate: [BaseResolver],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [InitResolver],
        children: []
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: AppErrorComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is working (Toda Haver), the only thing now that I encounter is that I have, is when I am trying to redirect from canActivate to home (for example). nothing happens. here is the code `this.router.navigate(['home'])` also tried to use `this.router.navigateByUrl('home');`. any idea?

Comment: try relative path `this.router.navigate(['/home'])`

Comment: Or else simply give full path `this.router.navigate(['er/site/home'])`

Answer (score 0):

Add `path: ''` and `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }` into your children

```
export const appRouter: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [BaseResolver],
    children: [
      { path: '', 
        component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [InitResolver],
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent,
        canActivate: [InitResolver],
        children: []
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: AppErrorComponent
      }, { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  //-------------------------------------------------------------
    {
      path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: {
      title: 'Home'

    }
  },
    {
      path: 'page2', component: Page2Component, pathMatch: 'full'
      data: {
      title: 'Page 2'
    }
    }]
```

If you have a previous section in url before the route
like 
http://localhost:00000/projectName/[route]/

you should add this is **providers** in **NgModule**

```
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/projectName' }]
```

Comment: adding APP_BASE_HREF didn't help